# Why the date of an email is in local Android time using JavaMail?

Tags: email, timezone, jakarta-mail

I've written a simple mail client that uses JavaMail to read emails.
When I get the Date of a message, it's expressed in the local time of my Android configuration.

For instance Message-->Date.getString() will give me a different time depending of my Android time zone configuration. However, the date of the message is on the server, right? So the Android time zone configuration should not affect anything.
Are Android and JavaMail secretely pass my time zone configuration to the server so that I receive a Date expressed indeed into my locale zone?

Well, that's not annoying I prefer this anyway, but I'm out of curiosity... why?!

Answer (score 0):

The server returns the date/time with the timezone so that the correct UTC/GMT time is stored in the Date object.  The Date.toString() method returns the date in the local timezone.